# ReCaptcha v3 in Blazor

Tags: blazor, recaptcha

How I can implement recaptcha v3 in blazor application? please provide me a complete example.

I am following below link for v2 but I want same functionality using recaptcha  v3.
https://github.com/sample-by-jsakamoto/Blazor-UseGoogleReCAPTCHA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Could you please provide me a solution as per my requirement?

Answer (score 2):

For the backend part it's the same.

For the frontend (Blazor WebAssembly):

1. Include the script in your `index.html` file: `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=XXX'></script>`
2. In your `scripts.js` add this function to your `window` so you can call it in C#:

```js
window.getCaptcha = async function () {
  await grecaptcha.ready(function() {});

  const token = await grecaptcha.execute('XXX', {action: 'formSubmission'})

  return token;
}
```

3. Call this JavaScript function to get the captcha before submitting it to backend

```cs
    [Inject]
    private IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }
    
    private async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        var captcha = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("getCaptcha");

        // Form submission code
    }
```